# SQL Server How to get Difference between two dates HH:MM:SS

Tags: sql-server, database, date, datetime

I need to get Difference between two dates as HH:MM:SS format I tried this

```
Select UserId,StartTime,EndTime,   DATEDIFF(HOUR,   StartTime, EndTime) AS  Hours,
 DATEDIFF(MINUTE, StartTime, EndTime) AS  Minutes,
  DATEDIFF(SECOND, StartTime, EndTime) AS  Seconds 

from Responses
```

but it didn't work well because it calculates hours , minutes and seconds Separately. 
For example: if the minutes greater than 60 minutes it won't change the hour

1:70:00 instead of 2:00:00

I need when the minutes greater than 60 minutes adds a new hour and when the sconds greater than 60 sconds add a new minutes

Thank you,

Answer (score 2):

```
declare @D1 datetime = '1jan2016 12:02:55'
declare @D2 datetime = '5jan2016 04:11:35'
Select @D2 - @d1, 
    Format(datediff(second, 0, @D2 - @d1)/3600, '0') + ':' +
    Format(datediff(second, 0, @D2 - @d1)%3600 / 60, '00') + ':' +
    Format(datediff(second, 0, @D2 - @d1)%3600 % 60, '00')
```

Comment: It's working, thank you so much,Can you please show me how can i do the avoid t-sql with Time DataType not string? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```
SELECT Userid, StartTime, EndTime,  convert(time(0),StartTime - EndTime) AS [Time in hh:mm:ss]
FROM Responses
```

Comment: this works when the difference is less than 24 hours

Answer (score 0):

You can use the cast function to do this instead of DATEDIFF,something like

> declare @StartDate datetime, @EndDate datetime
>
> select @StartDate = '10/01/2012 08:40:18.000',@EndDate='10/04/2012
>   09:52:48.000'
>
> Select CAST((@EndDate-@StartDate) as time(0)) '[hh:mm:ss]'

`

Comment: This also works only for the time *portion* of the difference